# NativeScript tns run android

Tags: android, macos, nativescript, tns

I keep getting an error on my mac

Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.

Can someone tell me how to fix this or install this manually to get it running on my mac!I have android 27 installed, how do I fix the path.I've tried everything

Comment: The support for SDK 27 is added via this PR https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/pull/3313 either updated to the lastest 3.4.1 NativeScript or use SDK >= 22 and <= 26

Comment: How did you install your Android SDK? What is the result of `tns doctor`?